# Why am I getting zero scores (accuracy) after loading model with keras.load_model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Can someone please help me? I have spent 12 hours training 4 models, and when I did load_model to assess them further (print confusion matrix and ROC curves), the accuracy and F1-scores are completely zero!

This is how I saved my model before, which produced (1.0 F1 score)

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

step_size_train=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                   steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                   validation_data=valid_generator, 
                   epochs=30)

model.save('C:/model.h5')
```

And then this is code from another notebook I was using to create the curves I neeed which produces all zeroes for my classification report!

```
reconstructed_model = keras.models.load_model("C:/model.h5")
reconstructed_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(0.0001),
             loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])



test_generator.reset() 

from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix,classification_report
import sklearn.preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

predictions = reconstructed_model.predict_generator(generator=test_generator,
                                       steps=test_generator.samples/test_generator.batch_size,
                                       max_queue_size=10,
                                       use_multiprocessing=False,
                                       verbose=1)


y_pred = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

true_classes = test_generator.classes

class_labels = list(test_generator.class_indices.keys())   

print(class_labels)

print(multilabel_confusion_matrix(test_generator.classes, y_pred))

report = classification_report(true_classes, y_pred, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)
```

I am using generators to load my data, I made sure the code is the same for that and that I preprocessed in the exact same way.. I am using TF=2.3.0, which I was reading that may have a bug with load_model (I tried sparse_cateogrical_crossentropy, did not work...) and also I have another transfer learning model which I trained a few days ago in the exact same way and used TF 2.3.0 and it's not producing the same issue

Can someone please help me as I am way, way out of time